# How to publish a hyperlink for a UNC path for a Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When a build finishes successfully, I would like to have a UNC path appear on that build page, that anyone can click on and have the folder open to the installer for that build.

For example, I have the following UNC path appearing in the description of a build run. (it's a plugin)  If you wanted to look at that folder, you have to copy it, open up explorer, paste it in...  It would be nice to just click on it or even ctrl click on it would work.  Example path include below.

\\foo\bar\Departmental\IT\QA\team\program-a\Builds\81

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin to have an html page displayed on the jenkins page for the build, put whatever links you want in there. If there is a way to use UNC from a web page, you'll be able to use it.

Comment: That will work, was hoping for something more elegant and more configuration screen based.  I can easily have the rake build script generate the HTML page though...

Comment: I'll hold out marking this the answer for a bit in hopes for other solution ideas...